# Python Generator expression: how to add AND conditions from a loop?

Tags: python, generator, generator-expression

Having the following distance matrix `dist`:

```
dist = [[[ 0, 0],
[ 5,  0],
[ 1,  0],
[ 1,  1],
[11,  3],
[ 3,  6],
[ 5,  5]],

[[ 5,  0],
[ 0,  0],
[ 6,  0],
[ 4,  1],
[ 6,  3],
[ 2,  6],
[10,  5]],

[[ 1,  0],
[ 6,  0],
[ 0,  0],
[ 2,  1],
[12,  3],
[ 4,  6],
[ 4,  5]],

[[ 1,  1],
[ 4,  1],
[ 2,  1],
[ 0,  0],
[10,  2],
[ 2,  7],
[ 6,  6]],

[[11,  3],
[ 6,  3],
[12,  3],
[10,  2],
[ 0,  0],
[ 8,  9],
[16,  8]],

[[ 3,  6],
[ 2,  6],
[ 4,  6],
[ 2,  7],
[ 8,  9],
[ 0,  0],
[ 8,  1]],

[[ 5,  5],
[10,  5],
[ 4,  5],
[ 6,  6],
[16,  8],
[ 8,  1],
[ 0,  0]]]
```

I need to build a `generator expression` with `AND` conditions like this:

```
gexp = (dist[:, :, 0] <= 1) & (dist[:, :, 1] <= 2)
```

meaning that I want a value of `True` when both conditions hold (for columns 0 and 1), like below (I printed it moving to a list comprehension syntax):

```
[array([[ True, False,  True,  True, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False,  True]])]
```

I have this list of columns:

```
columns = ['weight', 'height']
```

their thresholds:

```
thresholds = {'weight': 1.0, 'height': 1.0}
```

and their corresponding indexes:

```
indexes = {'weight': 0, 'height': 1}
```

I try to build my generator expression this way:

```
    dynamic_gexpr = [dist[:,:,indexes.get(column)] <= thresholds.get(column) for column in columns]
```

but I don't know how to add the AND conditions between one column and the other. The above expression seems to handle it as if they were more like OR conditions, giving the following output:

```
[array([[ True, False,  True,  True, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False,  True]]), array([[ True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True]])]
```

Comment: Could you share a more copy-pastable ndarray please? :-) ( a simple print will do)

Comment: Using `numpy`, you can do it like this: `l2 = np.array(l)` and `l3 = (l2[:, :, 0] <= 1) & (l2[:, :, 1] <= 2)`. Not sure if I understand your problem correctly though.

Comment: @yatu now it has been edited, I don't know why it prints without commas.

Comment: @Jeppe I need to build this expression at runtime using the values in columns, indexes and thresolds. All the conditions with <= threshold must be in AND. I don't know the right syntax to concatenate all the conditions separated by & (AND). Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I used list comprehension to apply the conditional which builds out the generator, doing it the other way around felt wrong. Anyway not sure if this is what you were going for.

```
x = ([second[0] <= 1 and second[1] <=2 for second in first] for first in dist)
for y in x:
    print(y)
```

Outputs:

```
[True, False, True, True, False, False, False]
[False, True, False, False, False, False, False]
[True, False, True, False, False, False, False]
[True, False, False, True, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, True, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, False, True, False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, True]
```

for the version the felt wrong incase its what you wanted

```
x = ((second[0] <= 1 and second[1] <=2 for second in first) for first in dist)

for y in x:
    print([next(y),next(y),next(y),next(y),next(y),next(y),next(y)])
```

which output the same

Now with writing a separate function to do the comparisons

```
def compare(a,b):
    return all([a[i] <= b[i] for i in range(len(a))])

x = ((compare(second, [1,2]) for second in first) for first in dist)

for y in x:
    print([next(y),next(y),next(y),next(y),next(y),next(y),next(y)])
```

Comment: I could have N conditions, which I'll know only at runtime, would it be possible to make this more programmatically without hardcoding the AND conditions or the indexes, as well as the thresholds?

Comment: added another bit of code where i break out the comparison bit so its more programmatic... maybe that'll help.

Answer (score 0):

This should extend if you add more columns. `arrays` will hold an array for each condition. Each of these is processed through `reduce` which in turn accumulates the `bitwise_and` of all arrays.

```
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce
columns = ['weight', 'height']
thresholds = {'weight': 1.0, 'height': 1.0}
indexes = {'weight': 0, 'height': 1}

l = np.array(dist)
arrays = [(l[:, :, indexes[column]] <= thresholds[column]) for column in columns]
l2 = reduce(lambda a, acc : np.bitwise_and(a, acc), arrays)
print(l2)
```

Outputs:

```
[[ True False  True  True False False False]
 [False  True False False False False False]
 [ True False  True False False False False]
 [ True False False  True False False False]
 [False False False False  True False False]
 [False False False False False  True False]
 [False False False False False False  True]]
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @1Z10 in its comments, `np.reduce` will ultimately be your friend here.

You should first build a matrix of boolean where each highest level row is the comparison of a subarray with its corresponding threshold. Then just use `np.reduce` and `nb.logical_and` on that matrix to get your result, whatever number of comparisons are involved:

```
dynamic_expr = np.logical_and.reduce(np.array(
    [dist[:, :, indexes[col]] <= thresholds[col]
     for col in columns]))
print(dynamic_expr)
```

output is:

```
[[ True False  True  True False False False]
 [False  True False False False False False]
 [ True False  True False False False False]
 [ True False False  True False False False]
 [False False False False  True False False]
 [False False False False False  True False]
 [False False False False False False  True]]
```